# Select unique combo plus one column

Tags: sql, distinct, inner-join

Can somebody tell me how to select a unique city/state combo from a table? I understand that you can select distinct values with

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city, state
FROM table
```

but I need to select combinations that are unique. In other words, I need to select combos that do not have the same city/state values with another entry. From what I can tell these are different.

What I'm trying to do is get those unique values and list the city/state combo with the name of the vendor. Here's what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT v.vendor_name, v2.vendor_state, v2.vendor_city
FROM vendors v JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT vendor_state, vendor_city
                FROM vendors) v2
ON v.vendor_state = v2.vendor_state and v.vendor_city = v2.vendor_city
```

Which results in

```
VENDOR_NAME                    VENDOR_STATE VENDOR_STATE
--------------------------------------------------------
Reiter's Scientific & Pro Books DC  Washington
Register of Copyrights          DC  Washington
National Information Data Ctr   DC  Washington
Zee Medical Service Co          IA  Washington
Small Press                     MI  Traverse City
Vision Envelope & Printing      CA  Gardena
Enterprise Communications Inc   VA  Mclean
Publishers Weekly               OH  Marion
.
.
.
```

As you can see, the combinations aren't unique (there is more than one listing for Washington, DC) I need to show only the city/state combos that appear once

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
SELECT vendor_name, vendor_state, vendor_city
FROM vendors v
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM vendors v2
    WHERE v2.vendor_id <> v.vendor_id
    AND v2.vendor_state = v.vendor_state
    AND v2.vendor_city = v.vendor_city
)
```

This will list vendors with a unique {state, city}. That is, vendors where no other vendor shares the same {state, city}.

---

You can also do it this way:

```
SELECT v.vendor_name, v.vendor_state, v.vendor_city
FROM vendors v
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vendor_state, vendor_id
    FROM vendors
    GROUP BY vendor_state, vendor_id
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
) u ON v.vendor_state = u.vendor_state AND v.vendor_city = u.vendor_city
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. Could you explain the WHERE NOT EXISTS block? I'm not sure I understand what the "SELECT 1" statement does

Comment: @afdave14 SELECT 1 is just "I don't care about any of the data in the row, but I have to select something so I will select a constant". You could change this to selecting the primary key instead if you wanted, since that's usually no (very little) cost to retrieve.

Comment: @afdave14 The WHERE NOT EXISTS block basically says I want to select vendors where there is not another vendor (different id) with the same {state, city}